# Найти количество вхождений строки в строку используя regex

Tags: c, регулярные-выражения

Для обычной заданной строки имеется вот такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char* string = "asdasdasd";
    char* substring = "as";
    int c = 0;
    char* p = string;
    int fndLen = strlen(substring);
    while (p)
    {
        p = strstr(p, substring);
        if (p) { 
            c++;
            p+=fndLen;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

Но как сделать, чтобы строка, которую ищем, задавалась через regex? То есть мне нужно вывести все совпадения (не только их подсчитать) регулярного выражения с regex в заданной строке.

Comment: Ну раз чистый С, а не С++, то у него, насколько я помню, регулярных выражений в стандарте нет. Так что зависит от того, чем именно вы пользуетесь для работы с ними.

Comment: regex.h использую

Comment: Я уж решил, что что-то пропустил... Взял "Язык С. Справочник" Принца и Кроуфорда от 2017 года, но там такой файл среди стандартных не упоминается... Перерыл все заголовочные файлы в VC++ 2019 — там такого тоже нет...

Comment: Вы где его откопали? Какая библиотека/исходники? Добавьте название или ссылку, чтоб мы могли помочь.

Comment: Да в простом гугле написал regex.h, и литературу там же... На маке всё работает, ничего дополнительно не скачивал. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expressions-in-c/

Comment: Поскольку вопрос так и остался открытым, могу просто предложить такой же вариант, как у вас с обычными подстроками — в цикле нашли, сместились, нашли...  Есть только — как и у вас в приведенном коде — проблема перекрытия, когда суффикс является заодно и префиксом, типа, ищем abcdefabc в строке abcdefabcdefabc — второе вхождение, перекрывающееся с первым, будет пропущено.